# node.js を crontab で実行するとパーミッションエラーが発生する

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

エラーの原因が全くわからないので、どなたか教えてください。
crontabでnodeを実行しようとするとパーミッションエラーが出ます。諸々のパスが正しいことは確認済みです。
なお、ユーザー名直下のディレクトリでファイルを作って実行したらなぜか上手くいきました。

crontabの内容：

```
* * * * * /nodeのパス /実行対象のパス>>　/実行対象のディレクトリのパス/log.txt 2>&1
```

ログ：

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/実行対象のパス'       
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:592:3)                                                    ~                                                                                              
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:460:35)                                               ~                                                                                              
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:18)                  ~                                                                                              
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)                             ~                                                                                              
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)                             ~                                                                                              
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) ~                                                                                              
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {                                         ~                                                                                              
  errno: -1,                                                                              ~                                                                                              
  syscall: 'open',                                                                        ~                                                                                              
  code: 'EPERM',                                                                          ~                                                                                              
  path: '/実行対象のパス'                                  ~                                                                                              
}                                                                                         ~
```

試したこと：関連するファイルやディレクトリに権限を与える、フルディスクアクセスでnodeを入れる

Comment: OSは何でしょうか？もしRHEL系のLinuxの場合、SE Linuxは有効ですか？もし有効の場合、`sudo setenforce 0`とした状態でcronが実行されるとどうなりますか？